# Save as dialog box while downloading a text file using php

Tags: php, html, textarea

I am saving a textarea content as a .txt file using below code.It will create a test.txt file.

```
function feed_text_download(){
if(isset($_POST['text_to_download']))
 {
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
   header('Content-type: application/txt');
   echo $_POST['text_to_download'];
   exit; //stop writing
 }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'feed_text_download');
```

I need to change the code in such a way that once I click save button, I will get  `save as` box and user can select filename instead of test.txt. I need help here.

Comment: save it where? in the server or the client?

Comment: User submit something to server, server process (eg: save to DB) and return to user with a dialog to asking user save file to somewhere in client side. Are you looking for this feature??

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't force a dialog box. This is up to the users's own browser settings. Most browsers these days are configured to download the file immediately to their downloads folder with the provided filename. If you want them to choose the name of the file, you'd have to have them choose before they click download.